# Vectors and queues C++

Tags: c++, vector

This is a follow on from an earlier question about how to condense a switch statement. I have used the input provided earlier but I am getting errors about how to insert my elements into the vector, but I thought this was how you inserted a vector in C++?

```
std::queue<myStruct > myQueue1, myQueue2, myQueue3, myQueue4, myQueue5

void change(float posx, float posy, int idNumber){  
    myStruct newDir;
    newDir.psX = posx;
    newDir.psY = posy;

    std::vector< std::queue<myStruct> > myVector (5);

    myVector.begin();
    myVector.insert (myQueue1);
    myVector.insert (myQueue2);
    myVector.insert (myQueue3);
    myVector.insert (myQueue4);
    myVector.insert (myQueue5);


    if (idNumber >= 1 && idNumber<= 5){
        myVector[idNumber-1].push (newDir);
        }


}
```

TIA Any help appreciated.

Comment: `myVector.begin();` does nothing - it's an expression that returns an iterator which nothing is done with, so it's thrown away. You may need to explain what your overall goal is a little bit.

Comment: The whole of vectors and other STL revolves around iterators as a sort of "location". `begin` just returns an iterator to the beginning, so that statement really does nothing. Each `insert` thereafter takes a location (this is where `begin` would help) to place the element. If you start with size 0, you can just `push_back` the elements onto the back, one at a time. Alternatively, if all of the queues are empty, you could use the vector constructor `vector (5, <empty queue>)` to make your vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vector::insert()` is for inserting a new element at a particular position (so it needs a position parameter).  You probably just want `push_back()` which will put the new item at the end of the vector. For this to work, you wouldn't want to initialize your vector as you do (which puts five empty queues on the vector); just default initialize the vector:

```
std::vector< std::queue<locaRef> > myVector;
```

But there's also the issue that your vector has elements with type `std::queue<locaRef>`, but the queues you're putting on the vector are `std::queue<MyStruct>`.  even if you fix the difference in types, you'll need to keep in mind that what will get put on to the vector are copies of the queue, which may or may not be what you want.  You may want the vector to take some kind of pointer or smart pointer to your queue objects if you don't want copies.

Comment: `push_back` won't work, because he allocated his vector with 5 empty members. `push_back` would just add more to the end.

Comment: I didn't want copies of the queues, I want the actual queues. So the whole method is a bit pointless if its no actually doing what the switch statement was before it. Hmmmm.

Comment: @EricBanderhide, if the queues aren't really preconstructed, you could just use a vector to hold the actual queues right from the beginning. Then just work with the queues in the vector instead of a different variable. Just pass the vector around by reference to change to the queues inside.

Comment: @Chris, many thanks for your help with these topics. I did what you said, took a little fiddling with the reference in the vector to work with my code but it works perfectly. Its cut 798 lines of code down to 380 and that was with only 5 items in the switches to test with. There were multiple switch statements and by using the same method all over its saved me loads, and its much more scalable! TYVM!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to hard-code the number of queues at 5 anyway, you can simply use an array instead of a `vector`.  Generally, you'd give your structure a simple constructor for convenience:

```
struct My_Struct
{
     My_Struct(float posx, float posy) : posx_(posx), posy_(posy) { }
     float posx_, posy_;
};

std::queue<My_Struct> my_queues[5];

void change(float posx, float posy, int id_number)
{
    if (id_number >= 1 && id_number <= 5)
        my_queues[id_number - 1].push(My_Struct(posx, posy));
    // else throw or assert so you'll see there's a problem...?
}
```